# How can I iterate a 2 dimensional array via pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have a 20x20 matrix.  I want to extract chunks of data from the matrix.  I have

```
int theMatrix[20][20] = {};//Full code initializes with #'s
int *theMatrixPointer = &theMatrix;
```

But then I get a compiler warning saying

> warning:  initialization from
>   incompatible pointer type

I went ahead and ran the code and it looks to be moving across the matrix from left to right.  At least in the short run.  The implementation:

```
//left to right with pointer;
while(theMatrixPointer)
{
    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    int four = 0;
    double currentProduct = 0;
    //int stop = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    {
        /*if(!theMatrixPointer)
        {
            stop = 1;
            break;
        }*/
        int currentValue = *theMatrixPointer++;
        printf("%d\n",currentValue);
        if(i == 0)
        {
            one = currentValue;
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            two = currentValue;
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            three = currentValue;
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            four = currentValue;
        }
    }
    /*if(stop)
        break;*/
    currentProduct = one * (double)two * three * four;
    printf("PRODUCT: %f\n",currentProduct);
    startPoint++;
    theMatrixPointer = startPoint;
}
```

...breaks over time as the data is garbage (big ints that are not in the matrix).  So, how can I properly iterate this matrix with a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the reason you get the warning is because `&theMatrix` is of type `int(*)[20][20]`, whereas `theMatrixPointer` is of type `int *`.  You want this:

```
int *theMatrixPointer = &theMatrix[0][0];
```

Secondly, the reason you are getting garbage is because you're going past the end of the array.  `while (theMatrixPointer)` will iterate until `theMatrixPointer == 0`.  But remember that `theMatrixPointer` is *an address*.  This won't be `0` until you've iterated over the *entire* address space and wrapped back round!

You are probably best off doing this:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        // matrixPointer[i][j] is the current element
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with going the route of i,j index iteration is that the algorithm I planned out doesn't work.  I need to pull blocks from the matrix 4 at a time.  After each pull the next index needs to go up by one with rinse-repeat.  On a similar, but different problem I solved this cleanly with a string and pointers, but this matrix is proving far more challenging.  I may need to rethink my approach.

Comment: @ssegvic Thanks guys I now know what it takes to do this with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338160). Basically, I think that dealing with theMatrix[20*20] is a wiser default approach than dealing with theMatrix[20][20].